# auto.arima mclapply Error in Forecast when trying to run parallel = TRUE

Tags: r, arima, forecast

Sorry, this is the very first post on this site any help would be appreciated.
I am getting the following Error when running this code.

```
fit_arima_Sales<-auto.arima(
         ForecastTS, d=1, D=1, xreg = Forecastxreg, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE, 
parallel = TRUE, num.cores = 14)
```

```
Error in mclapply(X = to.check, FUN = par.all.arima, max.order = max.order,  : 
  'mc.cores' > 1 is not supported on Windows
```

So I have been running this code for about 2 years on my old computer. ( Windows 10 , i9 with 8 Core, 16 Logical Processors)

I recently upgraded to a desktop that has windows 10 i9 with 8 core and 24 logical processors. and I am getting that error. I am pretty sure I downloaded every package that I had on my old computer.
I for the life of me cannot figure out why I am getting this error.

if I set parallel = FALSE and delete the num.cores = 14. the function will run. But only on 1 core.

Comment: So i decided to use an older version of R. i went with 4.0.3 ( same as my old computer) and moved all the packages over.
it now runs.. but it still only utilizes 1 Core. even with parallel set to TRUE.

Comment: I use `library(parallel)
detectCores()
library(doParallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
# Now run fit_resamples()

stopCluster(cl)` from [Tidy Modeling with R](https://www.tmwr.org/resampling.html#) Works on windows.